# Restrict Firebase to Communicate with Electron App

Tags: javascript, firebase, electron

Does anyone know how you can restrict access to a firebase realtime (or other) database from an Electron app? I know you can restrict it by pointing to the server your site is on, but since Electron is local, is there anything I can do to restrict access within Firebase rules or settings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Electron app is like any other client, web or mobil, the only way to restrict access is to have strong backend, in case of firebase, you have firebase rules, that let you define wich users or collection can be read or write.

the first step is to have an authentication method, if you're using firebase, use the auth service.

then you could write some rules, to let only authenticated users to have access to your database, write or read.

then while the user is authenticated, you can allow access to a certain part of the database depending of its users id, and so on.

you can go crazy with the rules, but that's the first step. you can read more about it on the firebase realtime database documentation. [rules docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

Comment: hi Alvaro, thank you for your answer, I do use firebase authentication but the issue is that on a normal website I can tell firebase to only allow communication with the host server (so if they take my code and run it it won't connect) but I'm wondering how to do the same thing with Electron (so if they run the code outside Electron it won't accept the connection).